# first argument of fgets function

Tags: c, file, pointers

In `fgets(s, 10, fp)`, `s` is the address from which reading from file "text.txt" starts. Am I correct?

If so, how does the function know where `s` points to when it is declared like this? I always thought that `s` would be a random free location in memory?
 Can someone explain more in depth why this code is reading from beginning of "text.txt"?

I am new to C.

```
fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        char *s
        printf("content of file:\n");
        while ((s = fgets(s, 10, fp)
        {
            printf("%s", s);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: `Am I correct?` no, first argument is pointer to array where read symbols will be stored, this array should be allocated already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is the location to store the bytes that get read from the file. (It's not "where in the file to start reading", it's "where to put the bytes after it's read them")

In this case, you don't set `s` to anything, so you don't know what it contains. (In other words, it's uninitialized)

So you're telling `fgets` to store the bytes it reads at some location, and you don't know what that location is. Maybe it's an un-allocated address (which would cause a segfault), maybe it's some memory that nothing is using (in which case it works), or maybe it points to something important that you just told `fgets` to overwrite (in which case it works, then crashes later when some other code tries to access the important thing). There's no way to know.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, my professor told us wrong about first argument it seems.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass a valid pointer as the first arugment to `fgets`, and it has to point to memory at least as large as indicated in the second argument.

You could change

```
char *s
```

to

```
char *s = malloc(10);
```

or

```
char s[10];
```

The code behind `fgets` will copy data from the file into the memory that you have allocated.

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed reading text into a random location in memory. This may crash, or succeed, or do something else entirely. Once you write to memory that's not yours, all bets are off.

Either declare `s` like this:

```
char s[10];
```

or allocate it:

```
s = malloc(10);
```